# Quote of some advanced text?

Tags: quotes, terminology, technical

I am trying to make a video and in it I need a piece of advanced text. You should get the feeling that this text is just advanced for the sake of being advanced, not for any practical reason, and being seen as a joke or similair.

(It is acceptable that this quote's complexity is perfectly reasonable in its own context, it should just look too complex to an average person.)

Maybe something from a very advanced philosophy course or a book about epistemology or perhaps a passage about linguistics with numerous abstraction levels and lots of referencing and triple/quadriple negations or something like that. Ideally, this shouldn't be just a technical text where every word seems like jibberish, but a quote where you sort of understand each word, but they are so "high class" and rare, and put together in such ways that you almost feel like the writer makes fun of you :P. Although if you do have techincal quotes like that, please respond too.

I have tried to google it, but how does one search for something like that?

Maybe some of you have some quotes written down that you have encountered earlier, or know some good book that I can lookup and look through to find this?

It should be longer than ~50 words. It should be syntactically correct for the most part. (It is ok if some parts of it are not, if those parts are so complicated that you have to study the quote first to notice it. But it shouldn't just be a mix of random words.)

Sorry if this is a wrong place to post this kind of query, it seemed appropriate though :)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you generate a fake postmodernism essay:

http://www.elsewhere.org/pomo/

Comment: If we're going to go that route, I'd rather suggest the Chomskybot: http://www.rubberducky.org/cgi-bin/chomsky.pl

Comment: +1 For mentioning the trusty Postmodernism Generator. And +1 for @JSBangs for the Chomskybot—I don't know why I've never met it before. There is also the Computer Science generator: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) is used in such cases

Comment: Lorem Ipsum doesn't look like advanced text, it looks like Latin, i.e. another language. While it's extremely useful, I don't believe it fits the bill.

Comment: Well, for me any text in Latin is advanced. And I believe it is the same for others since it is not live language